# Should I use Double as keys in a TreeMap?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, treemap

As described in the answer to [Double in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074781/double-in-hashmap), Doubles shouldn't be used in HashMaps because they are difficult to compare for equality. I believe my case is different, but I thought I'd ask to make sure since I didn't see anything about this.

I'm going to have a series of double values associated with objects, and I want them to be sorted by the double values. Is TreeMap an appropriate solution? Would there be a better one? The double values are generated a bunch of math, so the likelihood of a duplicate value is extremely low.

EDIT: I should clarify: all I need is to have this list of objects sorted by the doubles they're associated with. The values of the doubles will be discarded and I'll never call `map.get(key)`

Comment: Sounds like you should be safe.  You might add some fudge factor handling to prevent duplicates from happening just in case they do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ***Doubles shouldn't be used in HashMaps because they are difficult to compare for equality.***

- Will you ever try to `get` the values based on certain keys?

  - If **yes**, then the reasoning about "difficult to compare" applies and you should probably avoid such data structure (or always rely on `tailMap` / `headMap` / `submap` and fetch ranges of the map).
  - If **no** (i.e. you'll typically just do `for (Double key : map.keySet()) ...` or iterate over the `entrySet`) then I would say you're fine using `Double` as keys.

> ***The double values are generated a bunch of math, so the likelihood of a duplicate value is extremely low.***

- Is it a *bug* if you actually *do* get a duplicate?

  - If **yes** then it's not the right data structure to use. You could for instance use a [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Guava instead.
  - If **no**, (i.e. it doesn't matter which of the two values it maps to, because they can only differ by a small epsilon anyway) then you should be fine.

Comment: This is perfect. Both of my answers are "no" so I'm good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with doubles in tree maps is exactly the same as it is with doubles in hash map - comparing for equality. If you avoid calls of `treeMap.get(myDouble)` and stay with range queries instead (e.g. by using `submap`) you should be fine.

```
TreeMap<Double,String> tm = new TreeMap<Double,String>();
tm.put(1.203, "quick");
tm.put(1.231, "brown");
tm.put(1.233, "fox");
tm.put(1.213, "jumps");
tm.put(1.243, "over");
tm.put(1.2301, "the");
tm.put(1.2203, "lazy");
tm.put(1.2003, "dog");
for (Map.Entry<Double,String> e : tm.subMap(1.230, 1.232).entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This prints

```
1.2301=the
1.231=brown
```

See this snippet on [ideone](http://ideone.com/f37lc).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to sort them, the best thing would be to create a wrapper object around the double and the object, implement the "comparable" interface on this wrapper, and use a simple collection to sort them

Answer (score 0):

If you just want them sorted, there are better collections (for instance `SortedSet`). You can also use any list and use the utilities for sorting (I think they are in `java.util.Collection`).

Only use Maps and Tables when you want to directly access an item by its key.