# HashMap with double as key

Tags: java, hashmap, double

I found this post on stackoverflow that [Double in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074781/double-in-hashmap) states:

> I was thinking of using a Double as the key to a HashMap but I know floating point comparisons are unsafe

But I can't really find out **why** it is unsafe to use doubles as key in your hashmap. Could you guys explain that to me?

Comment: What do you want to know that isn't already explained by the many answers to the existing question?

Comment: They are't "unsafe". It may lead to unexpected results if your expectation is incorrect, which it is likely to be.

Answer (score 1):

in simple words the key you are using for map, will be changed very much for even a small decimal change in fractions, the probability of missing the values is much higher.

hashCode of java.lang.Double says
`(int)(v^(v>>>32))`